# MIPS Store Word (sw)

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm trying to store a integer into `$s0`, and this is in a loop label.

But the problem is that I will be printing an integer and having it save in `$s0`.

I have done the following

```
sw $t7,0($s0)
addi $s0,$s0,4
```

I thought the following would allow me to store each integer in a slot in `$s0`, but if I `lw`, I only get the last integer that was printed

Code Below: In bold I have attemped to store a word but like you said it overwrites
This is a homework problem, so I really want to learn, please offer some direction so I'll know next time

```
        .data                               


n1:     .asciiz "\n"                        #ASCII for a new line

        .align 2                            



name:   .asciiz "Fibonacci\n\n\n"               #Lab Title and Student Name
        .align 2

msg1:   .asciiz "Fibonacci result " #note the space
        .align 2                            


msg2:   .asciiz " is "                      #note the space
        .align 2

**array:  .space 20                     #define the array**

        .text                               #
        .globl  main                        #declare main to be global



main:   



        la  $a0,name                        #load the ram address of "name" into $a0
        li  $v0,4                           #system call, type 4, print a string, $a0
        syscall                             #call the "OS" to perform operation

        li  $t2,0                           # $t2 :=0; initial value of F(n-2)
        li  $t1,1                           # $t1 :=1; initial value of F(n-1)

        li  $t4,0                           #index, n.

                                            #loop is a local Variable
        li  $t5,11                      #loading immediate preset value for $t5 




        **la $t7,array                      #load address (array) into $t7**





loop:   addu    $t0,$t1,$t2                 # F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2)

        **#Only print the last 5 numbers**
        sub $t3,$t5,$t4
        li $t6,5
        bgt $t3,$t6,Printl


        la $a0,msg1                         # $a0 := address of message 1
        li $v0,4                            #system call, type 4, print a string
        syscall                             #call the "OS"

        move    $a0,$t4                     # $t4 contains the current value of n
        li  $v0,1                           #system call, type 1, print an integer $a0
        syscall                             #call the "OS"

        la $a0,msg2                         # $a0:=address of "msg2"
        li $v0,4                            #system call, type 4, print a string
        syscall                             #call the "OS"

        move    $a0,$t0                     # $a0 :=$t0, which is F(n)
        li  $v0,1                           #system call, type 1, print an integer $a0
        syscall                             #call the "OS"


        **sw $s0, 4($t7)**





        la  $a0,n1                          # $a0 := address of "n1"
        li  $v0,4                           #system call, type 4, print a string
        syscall                             #call the "OS"




        addi    $t4,1                       # $t4 := $t4 + 1; increment n
        move    $t2,$t1                     # $t2 := $t1; old F(n-2) because old F(n-1)
        move    $t1,$t0                     # $t1 := $t0; old F(n-2) because old F(n)



        beq     $t5,$t4,Exit            #Conditional Check | exit







        j       loop                        # branch unconditionally to loop ($t3 != 0)

Exit:   
        la $a0,n1                           # $a0 := address of message 1
        li $v0,4                            #system call, type 4, print a string
        syscall                             #call the "OS"

        #la $t7,array
        #li $v0,1
        #sw $s0, 4($t7)
        #syscall


        li      $v0,10                      #system call, type 10, standard exit
        syscall                             #call the "OS"

Printl: 
        addi $t4,1
        move $t2,$t1
        move$t1,$t0
        j loop
```

Comment: `sw` is storing a single word into a single register. If it's in a loop then you're overwriting it with the same value every time. So `lw` will only return the value you stored the last time through the loop.

Comment: so what can I do?, could you give me a hint please?

Comment: @BlahBlah You need to be more specific and post more code.

Comment: added more code =) Sorry about that

Comment: anyone have any helpful hints?

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if you're still here. :) But if you are, and you're still doing MIPS by chance after two semesters, here's something that might help.

You already noted that `sw $s0, 4($t7)` is going to write the contents of $s0 to the address pointed to by ($t7 + 4). Since the value of $t7 is never changed, you will keep writing the contents of $s0 to that same address over and over.

If you want to store the contents of $s0 to consecutive words starting at `array`, you will need to initialize the pointer, do what you want to do with it, then increment it.

```
la $t7,array
loop:
# do something to set $s0
sw $s0, 0($t7)
# do something to break out of loop if condition is met
addi $t7, 4
j loop
```

Don't forget that you've defined `array` as 20 *bytes* - that's just 5 words.